# variable is undefined when attached to callback function (Javascript / Dojo)

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, global-variables, arcgis-js-api

I have this variable declared at global scope:

```
  var wait;
```

then, inside of an event listener, I assign a function to  this variable, then attach a callback function: (I am using Dojo, via the ArcGIS Javascript API)

```
  wait = doThis();

  wait.addCallback(function (){

    doNextThing();

  });
```

doThis removes some layers from a map:

```
 doThis(){
        var layer = map.getLayer("mapLayer");
         if (layer) {
             map.removeLayer(layer);
}
```

..but when I run it, I get an error saying 'wait' is undefined...

I have similar syntax elsewhere in my code that works...is it because I am assigned the callback within an event listener? If so, is there a workaround? I really need doThis() to be completed before doNextThing() begins.

Comment: wait = doThis(); assings the **result** of 'doThis()'. If 'doThis' is a function, then you should try 'wait = doThis'

Comment: I don't think that's it, that results in an error: 'wait.addCallback is not a function'

Comment: What does `function doThis` look like?

Comment: `doThis` doesn't return anything. Where do you expect `addCallback` to come from?

Comment: I added a return value but thats doesn't change the result.

Comment: what I really don't understand is why 'wait' is undefined ///

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript function always returns value and if you skip `return` keyword inside function then it returns `undefined` automatically. And in your `doThis` code there is no return statement. This is why `wait` gets undefined and fails on next step.

What should be returned? From shown example we can only deduce that object returned from `doThis()` offers `addCallback` function. Since ArcGIS is built upon Dojo Toolkit it is probably the [Deferred](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.7/dojo/Deferred) object. [What returns Deferred](https://developers.arcgis.com/search?q=Deferred&start=0&product=js-api-arcgis) is open question having no other clues from your example.